# Delete query won't work

Tags: c#, sql, delete-row

I'm trying to remove a row from the database that has the same ART as is selected in the combobox. I had it working before but when I changed the database it was supposed to delete it from it stopped working and gave me a [error message](https://imgur.com/CJAZfUk). I did change the database connection etc acording to the database change.

The error message (Hoping image works)
[image]
I don't know why it says "conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'R06018' to data type int" since I don't have a value of R06018 anywhere in the code, nor is it the selected row.

the code I tried after the delete stopped working, it's just the delete without any thing extra (I know it doesn't dispose but the program crashes when it tries to read, and it's just for finding the issue)

```
try
  {
   SqlCommand inkoopartdelete = new SqlCommand("delete from ART where ART=" + artnr.SelectedItem + "", Connectie.connMEVO);
   drMEVO = inkoopartdelete.ExecuteReader();
   MessageBox.Show(this.artnr.SelectedItem + " verwijderd.");
  }
  catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show("" + e); }
```

The old code after I changed the db connection (set as comment since I tried a smaller bit of code for the delete)

```
  //SqlCommand inkoopdelete = new SqlCommand("delete from ART where ART=@art", Connectie.connMEVO_ART);
  //inkoopdelete.Parameters.Add("@art", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = artnr.SelectedItem;
  //drMEVO = inkoopdelete.ExecuteReader();
  //try
  //{
  //    while (drMEVO.Read())
  //    { }
  //    MessageBox.Show(this.artnr.SelectedItem + " verwijderd.");
  //}
  //catch (SqlException v)
  //{
  //    MessageBox.Show("" + v);
  //}
  //inkoopdelete.Dispose();
```

I hope any of you could help me, since I can't find the issue.

Found the issue, see accepted awnser for error in test code, real error seems to be me reading over a part of the code -_- ...srry

Comment: debug and see what value is coming in `artnr.SelectedItem`. The error says that you are rting to convert varchar value to int

Comment: What is the datatype of the FIELD ART in your Table ART? (Better trying to have clearer names like ArtID or ArtNo for your field)

Comment: Well, the "old" code uses parameters, so please prefer that to... not using parameters. Second, going from the exception message, I'd guess that the `ART` field in the database is of type `int`, but `artnr.SelectedItem` in code is `string`, which will be passed (or *is* passed in the old code) as `varchar`. That won't work.

Comment: ART is a varchar field and the value from the combobox (artnr) is a possible combination of letters and digits up to 8 characters. I tried to do it with multiple like "010F3010" and "011".

Comment: @Corak since ART is a letter and digit combination it is a varchar field and  i would use parameters in the code i just tried to see if i could find the error with the smaller code that doesnt have parameters.

Comment: You are missing single quotes around + artnr.SelectedItem + . But why revert to not using bind parameters?

Comment: When you build the command yourself like that (which again is a bad idea), you need to surround the `string` value with single quotes. Otherwise it will not be recognised as `(n)varchar` and will probably be (tried to be) interpreted as `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ART field is of type nvarchar then, if you really want to use string concatenations, you should enclose your string value in single quotes and write

```
SqlCommand inkoopartdelete = new SqlCommand(@"delete from ART 
           where ART='" + artnr.SelectedItem + "'", Connectie.connMEVO);
```

That's a valid enough reason to revert as soon as possible to use a parameterized query as you have initially. Other reasons to avoid this is the fact that if your value has an embedded single quote the Whole text becomes syntactically wrong. And, finally, string concatenation is the open door for Sql Injection Attacks

A last note. If you want to execute a query like DELETE/INSERT or UPDATE do not use ExecuteReader. It works, but it is not necessary to build an SqlDataReader for that kind of queries. Just use

```
 int affectedRows = inkoopartdelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Strange, the query you gave does work like it's supposed to but i dont get why the old one would break then. but at least i can try to progress now.

Comment: what is the reason for the int affectedrows? since i just want it to delete the row (it shouldn't be able to have more then 1 with the ART) so would "drMEVO = inkoopartdelete.ExecuteNonQuery();" work as well or how should i see that example?

Comment: The ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows that (in this case) have been deleted. You could implement some kind of logic with this value like displaying a message to your user if the value is 1 (like a confirm), instead, if it is zero, you could inform your user that no row has been deleted. The decision to use that return value is up to you, but it is here only to show that ExecuteNonQuery returns simply an integer instead of building a complex object with live connection to the database like ExecuteReader.

Comment: Ah thanks, ill just use it without having it return a int then since that seems to work to :) . Still learning more about sql so it's new to me and i suppose i should use it a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Change below statement :
You have to give single quote.

```
SqlCommand inkoopartdelete = new SqlCommand("delete from ART where ART='" + artnr.SelectedItem + "'", Connectie.connMEVO);
```